# How can I set character not to cross over it's own mesh?

Tags: animation, rigging, rigidbody

I currently have the following character and when I animate it, it doesn't respect it's own body.

As you can see in this image the arms go into his head.

[image]

The following settings are what's displayed in the properties:
[image]

I selected the main Toon selection and then I added a RigidBody constraint but that didn't work.  Collisions -> Shape -> Compound Parent says "There are no child rigid bodies".  Any idea how I can resolve this?